# Ask again for a document in email

Tags: applications, email, deadlines

I want to write an email to a person that I already contacted to remind him about an application deadline, and that I need a document from him that I already requested but still got no response and the deadline is approaching. Any suggestion please?

Comment: _"Dear Jane Doe! As the application-deadline is aproaching on 31.12.2021, I want to kindly remind you to  send me the document mentioned in my previous mail. Best regards, John Foobar"_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Gnat, it’s not necessary a job application deadline. It could be a building permission application that costs the companies six digits if the application deadline is missed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Indeed it is not a job application deadline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you can do, you can either wait or chase the person. Waiting will not help you, so chase the person. If you have their number, call them. Otherwise, a polite but urgent email is the way to go. Explain the situation with the deadline. Similar to what iLuvLogix suggests:

> Dear [Person],
>
> As the application deadline is approaching on 31.12.2021, I want to kindly remind you to send me document [X], like I requested in my previous mail. If anything is unclear or you need more information, please contact me on my personal phone number on +123456789.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> danix

Comment: If you chase the person, a rule of thumb is that you make it more work not to respond than to respond. So daily call if you don’t hear from them, then email cc’d to your manager and theirs.